# CSV file adding default row by using excel

Tags: marketing-cloud, csv, excel

As you can see in **the image below** I'm trying to open a CSV file by using Excel but every time I tried there is a row that I don't need excel add it by default, how can I remove this option I don't need this row

Image : [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8SGy.png

Answer (score 2):

I would assume this is because you did not check the `Include column headers` box on export, so it is assuming that the top row is just another row and not the headers for your data.

[image]

The above is from a manual UI export, You can also find it in a Data Extract Activity (in Automation Studio) as `Has Column Headers` in the Configuration step. Like below:

[image]

I believe also in Excel there is a way to turn on/off your headers. Might want to check **[this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-excel-table-headers-on-or-off-c91d1742-312c-4480-820f-cf4b534c8b3b)** link that tells you how to toggle this.